Is it possible to support multiple path bases in ASP.NET Core MVC project?
I have an ASP.NET Core MVC application which is hosted on IIS with an application URL mysite.com/bcx. Previously I had a separate Identity Server project which was hosted on mysite.com/identity, but now I'm trying to migrate the authentication stuff to the ASP.NET Core MVC project, but I need to preserve the /identity path for the compatibility with the client's SSO service.
My routing is configured this way:
app.UseRouting();
app.MapControllerRoute(name: "default", pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
app.MapControllerRoute(name: "integration", pattern: "integration/{controller}/{action}");
app.MapControllerRoute(name: "v2", pattern: "v2/{controller}/{action}");

app.MapRazorPages();

// add test endpoint for local development
if (env.IsDevelopment() || env.IsEnvironment("localhost"))
{
    app.MapGet("/test-endpoint", () => Results.Ok(new { success = true }));
}

app.Map("/clear-cache", (IMemoryCache commonMemoryCache) =>
{
    if (commonMemoryCache is MemoryCache memoryCache) memoryCache.Compact(1d);

    return Results.Ok();
});

Controller for which I need to preserve /identity in path is:
[Route("[controller]/[action]")]
public class SamlController : Controller

I tried to map a different controller route, add "identity" to the [Route] attribute or manually change the path base, but none of these helped. The site recognizes endpoints like mysite.com/bcx/identity but not the mysite.com/identity.
app.Use((context, next) =>
{
    if (context.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/identity"))
    {
        context.Request.PathBase = new PathString("/identity");
    }
    else
    {
        context.Request.PathBase = new PathString("/bcx");
    }
               
    return next();
});


You can try to define a route explicitly for /identity paths by using the MapControllerRoute method before other routes are defined.
